# Cookies Not Working Properly

Tags: php, cookies

this is my code in logout.php

```
    <?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie-username']) || isset($_COOKIE['cookie-password'])) {

    setcookie("cookie-username", NULL, time()-60*60*24*100);
    setcookie("cookie-password", NULL, time()-60*60*24*100);
}
    header( 'Location: ../login' ) ;
    ?>
```

I can confirm the cookies exist, If I do a while loop I get

**Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 79 bytes) in **/home/ios/public_html/logout.php** on line **5**

which means It cannot delete the cookies...
I've done a lot of googling, but I can't figure out why it won't delete said cookies...

Help?
Thanks In Advance

edit:
proof of cookies:
http://cl.ly/1c31120de4b722518b05

creation of cookies:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        try {           
            if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password']) || trim($_POST['username']) =='' || trim($_POST['password']) =='') {               throw new Exception('All Fields Are Required!');
            }
            $username = strtolower($_POST['username']);
            $password = md5(strtolower($_POST['password']));

            include('classes/config.php');

                        [SQL REMOVED]
            foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                $dbPassword = $row['password'];
            }  

            if (!isset($dbPassword)) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid Username or Password!');
            }

            if ($dbPassword == $password) {
                 if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookie-username']) || !isset($_COOKIE['cookie-password'])){ 

                    $days = 1;

                    if (strtolower($_POST['remember']) == 'on') {
                        $days = 30;
                    }


                    setcookie("cookie-username", $username, time()+60*60*24*$days, "/");
                    setcookie("cookie-password", $password, time()+60*60*24*$days, "/");

                }  

                   echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=../index">';    
            }   
            else if ($dbPassword != $password) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid Username or Password!');
            }   
        }

            catch (Exception $e) {
                $exception = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: well, it never exits the while loop, so the cookies never get deleted. So i'm 99.99999999999999999% sure it's there.

Comment: .. and that is the reason for the fatal error. See @meze's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the while loop. `setcookie` doesn't affect $_COOKIE.

If it doesn't help, try this:

```
<?php
    setcookie("cookie-username", NULL, time()-60*60*24*100, "/", ".yourdomain.com");
    setcookie("cookie-password", NULL, time()-60*60*24*100, "/", ".yourdomain.com");
    header( 'Location: ../login' ) ;
?>
```

PS: Also it's a bad idea to store login/password in cookies, for an authentication purpose it's better to store a flag in session

Comment: +1 this is it. It's effectively an infinite loop, filling the memory until it crashes.

Comment: ok, so its infinite, now that I changed it back to just an if statement, it still cannot delete cookie.

Comment: it becomes an infinite redirect loop, and the cookies never delete.

Comment: updated. if it doesn't help can you show how you set those cookies ? are you sure they still exist in your browser?

Comment: Then simple setcookie("cookie-username", NULL, time()-60*60*24*100, "/") should remove the cookie. Try to comment out call to header and check if it gives any warnings. You said redirect loop. Does /login perfom any redirects? I'd check the code of that redirect too

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
setcookie('cookie-username', 0, -1);
setcookie('cookie-password', 0, -1);
header('Location: example.com/path/login');
?>
```

1. This functions don't throw anything then `try` is not usable for you.
2. `$_COOKIES` is refreshing only when script start then if you erase cookie, you will see on next refresh results.

Comment: same thing happens with that.